# Pascal passing object of inheritance class to procedure

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have types declared as:

```
TPlayer = class(TObject) 
TBullet = class(TObject) 
TEnemy = class(TObject)
```

and objects:

```
Player: TPlayer;
PlayerBullets: Array[1..20] of TBullet;
Enemies: Array[1..20] of TEnemy;
EnemyBullets: Array[1..20] of TBullet;
```

Now I want to create TBullet constructor, which can process informations from both Player and Enemies. In short, I want this constructor to handle both TPlayer and TEnemy objects.

My idea is:

```
constructor TBullet.Create(const Source: TObject);
```

Sadly it does not work. How to do this?

EDIT:
My exact problem is: when I pass TPlayer or TEnemy object to this constructor it doesn't see atributes of those objects. For example: TPlayer has attr xPos. If I use Bullet.Create(Player) and in TBullet.Create I use Source.xPos I get an error.

Comment: In what sense does this not work? You can pass instances of any class to `TBullet.Create`. If you want help you'll need to make a little more effort to explain your problem, what you want to achieve, what you tried, and how it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 3 ways to achieve that.

1. Have TPlayer and TEnemy both derive from the same base class that have all the information TBullet's constructor need, and have the constructor parameter of that type.
2. Define an interface contains all the information needed by TBullet and have TPlayer and TEnemy implement that interface
3. Leave everything "as is" and manage the different class in a "hard coded" manner in TBullet's constructor.

By that I mean:

```
constructor TBullet.Create(const Source: TObject);
var 
  vPlayer : TPlayer;
  vEnemy : TEnemy;
begin
  if Source is TPlayer then
  begin
    vPlayer := TPlayer(Source);
    [Do whatever with vPlayer]
  end else if Source is TEnemy then
  begin
    vEnemy := TEnemy(Source);
    [Do Whatever with vEnemy]
  end;
end;
```

Which solution is the best? That could be a debate in itself and largely dependant on your specific situation.  Based solely on the name of your class, I'd guess option 1 could be valid. A "TCharacter" class could be created and use as a base calss for both TCharacter and TEnemy.  But this is mere speculation at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: Upvote for actually having 3 solutions. 4th is probably something IDispatch based :-)

Comment: @Viters see also https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory/delphi

Answer (score 0):

In windows there is little difference in inheriting from a parent with the common methods (could be abstract in the parent ) or implementing an interface (when again the behavior could be customized ). 
If you have an enumeration commonParticipant( cpPlayer, cpEnemy) then Windows allows access to the ultimate parent IUnknown and then down again to a child interface that identifies the methods peculiar to that child, i.e. you can pass an ICommonParticipant including the commonParticipant and then work with either a iPlayer or IEnemy interface